# Parse dara returneed from JSON with jQuery to HTML

Tags: jquery, json

How can i get the value returned by

```
$.getJSON('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27https://www.facebook.com/GreenSpaIasi/%27&format=json', function (data) {

});
```

to

```
<h3 data-speed="3000" data-from="0" data-to="HERE" class="number_counter bold count text-light start_timer counted">HERE</h3>
```

I have tried this way but is not working:\

```
$.getJSON('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27https://www.facebook.com/GreenSpaIasi/%27&format=json', function (data) {
    var value = data["like_count"];
    alert(value);
});
```

Thanks

Comment: try [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an array so u need to access like this `data[0]["like_count"];`

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url=%27https://www.facebook.com/GreenSpaIasi/%27&format=json', function (data) {
    var value = data[0]["like_count"];
    console.log(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```